# Update Viber without loosing data?

Tags: viber

How do we update viber (from 7.0 to current) without loosing any data ? I see plenty of information on installing new instance but non on updating it.

I installed viber by

downloading deb :

`$ wget https://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/viber.deb`

and running the cmd :

`$ sudo apt install ./viber.deb`

If I happen to download and install a newer version without removing my current version, will it be updated or can I run into problems ?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the cache file of viber with new name(viber.bak) and after installation of new viber you can rename the old cache ot viber it should keep all the old data.
And if you also want to retore old configs then you can do same to config files to.

The cache file can be found on

```
~/.cache/viber
```

and config can be found on

```
~/.config/viber
```

Comment: in `~/.cache/` i only see `Viber Media S.à r.l/ViberPC/qmlcache` containing abt 6.9mb of 333 `*.qmlc`files.

Comment: in `~./config/autostart/` i see only file `Viber.desktop`

Comment: i see my previous imgs thumbnails in `~/.ViberPC/*` which is `5,981 items, totalling 263.2 MB`

Comment: `~/Douments/ViberDownloads` contains 3,426 items, totalling 3.2 GB, which has the old downloads.

Comment: i assume i should backup these files and then restore them after updating ? just want to know, have you updated your viber, and had your old data & history remaining ?

Comment: the qmlc file must have all th configs and stuffs;
while the downloads flder have the assets used or stored in viber like the images you shared or revived.
So you can back both them up or just keep the qlmc